# Repainting in a Windows Application

Tags: c#, windows

i have used two methods in windows application namely for event paint method name is Graph_Paint() and other event is for load Graphs_Load() and i am using scroll bars for that window when i drag the scroll bar it is repainting again and calling the method Graph_Paint()
unable to see the correct picture of the graph.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/502ac0b588.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/502ac0b588.jpg)

the first URL image is the original one when i drag the scroll bar the image getting changed to second URL

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4c53ab4b2b.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/4c53ab4b2b.jpg)

Comment: -1, for pictures that are not available which means you don't read the question after posting whether it is all right or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the screen before you paint the repositioned graph.

Comment: please tell how to clear the screen while moving the scroll bar please help.

Comment: I am assuming you are drawing your graph to a pictureBox control, in which case set the image to null and invalidate it.